# Lectura de archivo en memoria interna con Android versión 7

Tags: android

Reformo la pregunta para que sea más precisa y ajustada a lo que he comprobado.
La cuestión es que si se crea un Bundle en la actividad principal para pasar datos a otras actividades, cuando la aplicación es comenzada, ese Bundle se crea nuevo y debería estar vacío osea "null". Pues eso ocurre en todas las versiones de Android excepto en la 23 y la 25 en las que por arte de magia ese Bundle aparece lleno de no se qué. Quizás sea un bug ya que en la 24 no ocurre. También, otra cosa que he observado es que cuando se ejecuta la aplicación en modo debug el problema no ocurre y el Bundle aparece "null" como debería ser por lógica. Dejo el código de una aplicación sencilla para que se comprenda.

```
package jas.pruebabundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView texto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    String text;

    if (bundle == null) {

        text = "Acabo de entrar en la aplicación";

        }

    else {

        text = bundle.getString("TEXTO");

        }

    texto.setText(text);

    Button bot = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);

    bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, OtraActividad.class);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

            }

        });
    }

}

activity_main.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
tools:context="jas.pruebabundle.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Boton"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>  

OtraActividad.java

package jas.pruebabundle;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class OtraActividad extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otraactividad);

    Button bot2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton2);

    bot2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();

            bundle2.putString("TEXTO", "El bundle pasÃ³ el texto a la actividad principal");

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

            intent.putExtras(bundle2);

            startActivity(intent);

            finish();

            }

        });
     }
}

activity_otraactividad.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
tools:context="jas.pruebabundle.OtraActividad">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Boton"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿Pides los permisos desde el código java?

Comment: puedes agragar el código que lee el archivo o el manifest.xml o los logs de la aplicacion o al menos una imagen. La pregunta es un poco confusa

Comment: Creo haber encontrado cuál es el problema. Antes que nada muchas gracias por contestar.

Comment: La cuestión es que si se crea un Bundle en la actividad principal para pasar datos a otras actividades, cuando la aplicación es comenzada, ese Bundle se crea nuevo y debería estar vacío osea "null". Pues eso ocurre en todas las versiones de Android excepto en la 23 y la 25 en las que por arte de magia ese Bundle aparece lleno de no se qué. Quizás sea un bug ya que en la 24 no ocurre. También, otra cosa que he observado es que cuando se ejecuta la aplicación en modo debug el problema no ocurre y el Bundle aparece "null como debe ser por lógica. Espero antes de cerrar la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: Sería bueno agregaras el código, me parece raro lo que comentas, aùn mas que no ocurre en API 24, sería interesante tener más información.

Comment: package...

import...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ...
   private int numero;
   ...
   
   protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
      ...
      
      //Declaración del Bundle de marras. Si la aplicación
      //acaba de arrancar su valor debe ser null
      Bundle bundle = getIntent.getExtras();
      if (bundle != null) {
         numero = bundle.getInt ("NUMERO");
         }
      else {
         numero = 1000;
         }
         
      ...
      
      }
  }      
      
Espero que este lo aclare mejor.

Comment: Este código no muestra en que forma implementaste la persistencia en la tarjeta SD en las versiones anteriores o como falla en la versión mencionado. Si existe una incompatibilidad entre Android 7.1.1 y versiónes anteriores sería una pregunta muy interesante, pero se necesitan más informaciónes (código de persistencia, manifesto con privilegios, código para solicitar privilegios del usuario etc.). Podrías proveer eso?

Comment: Los accesos a memoria interna, que yo sepa, no necesitan permisos pues es el mismo Android el que los otorga automáticamente. En el "manifest" no solicito ningún permiso por ese motivo, no se necesitan otros. Por otro lado, lo que falla es el Bundle y éste se aloja en la memoria temporal no teniendo nada que ver con cómo se guarda el archivo. Voy a crear dos actividades y pondré el código para que lo veáis más claro aunque lo que voy a hacer es de lo más básico y ya conoceréis cómo se hace.

Comment: Por favor usad el código que he puesto arriba para crear un proyecto nuevo. No es necesario que modifiquéis el Manifest ni el Gradle. Ejecutad el código en un emulador y, cuando esté instalado, salid de la aplicación para acto seguido volver a entrar arrancándola en el emulador. Repetid esto en versiones 25 e inferiores, veréis entonces lo que quería decir desde el segundo comentario.